# Как исправить ошибку Module parse failed: Unexpected token при билде проекта?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Я подключаю библиотеку для подсветки синтаксиса vue3-highlightjs

Но при билде webpack выдает ошибку. В ошибке указано , что проблема с css этой библиотеки.
СSS вроде обычный.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть? Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?
Пробовал другую библиотеку, но вылетает та же ошибка.

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

СSS файл из-за которого она вылетает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так во vue импортирую css:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен любой подсказке. Спасибо.

Comment: Приветствую. Код лучше прикладывать текстом, а не скриншотами

Comment: Учту. Спасибо. Вот полный текст ошибки:                                                                                 
  ERROR in ./node_modules/vue3-highlightjs/styles/a11y-dark.css 6:0
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    | 
    | /* Comment */
    > .hljs-comment,
    | .hljs-quote {
    |   color: #d4d0ab;
     @ ./src/js/PartsIndex/TheSettingsCatalog.js 6:0-47
     @ ./src/js/script-parts-index.js